# Epson printer prints empty pages

Tags: networking, printing, epson

I successfully installed Epson Stylus Photo PX370 in Ubuntu 16 with cups as a network printer. 
Any print command makes the printer throw out all blank pages untill switched off.

Comment: Did you install a proprietary driver?

Comment: No, the standard Gutenprint. I searched for an Epson driver but could not find one.

Comment: Problem solved: The printer worked correctly from Debian (raspberry Pi). There the driver was for Epson... PX710W. In Ubuntu the driver was for Epson... 720. That makes the difference!!